# "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job aborted" using Databricks and spark connector

Tags: pyspark, neo4j, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have used Databricks to ingest my knowledges graph (stored as nodes/edges in delta tables (parquets)) to neo4j

```
FORMAT = "org.neo4j.spark.DataSource"
BATCH_SIZE = 25000

URL = "***://***"
USERNAME = "***"
PASSWORD = "***"
DATABASE = "***"

neo4jconfig = {
    "url" : URL,
    "database": DATABASE,
    "authentication.type":"basic",
    "authentication.basic.username" : USERNAME,
    "authentication.basic.password" : PASSWORD,
    "batch.size": BATCH_SIZE,
    "relationship.source.save.mode" :"Overwrite",
    "relationship.target.save.mode" :"Overwrite",
    "schema.optimization.type": "NODE_CONSTRAINTS",
    "relationship.save.strategy": "keys",
    "relationship.source.node.keys": "source:id",
    "relationship.target.node.keys": "target:id",
    "transaction.retries": "20",
    "transaction.retry.timeout": 1000,
}
```

I already ingested the nodes and now i'm trying to ingest the edges it took 8 hrs

```
done_edges = ["people_friends.delta/"]

def writeEdgeIntoNeo4j(edge: str, input_path: str):
    print(edge)
    edge_df = a.read(input_path + f"edges/{edge.strip('/')}")
    labels = edge_df.select('label').distinct().collect()
    for label in labels:
        filtered_df = edge_df.filter((F.col("label") == label[0]))
        print(f"label : {label[0]}")
        for relation in filtered_df.select('source_label', 'target_label').distinct().collect():
            print(f"source : {relation['source_label']} :: target : {relation['target_label']}")
            neo4jconfig["relationship"] = label[0]
            neo4jconfig["relationship.source.labels"] = f":{relation['source_label']}"
            neo4jconfig["relationship.target.labels"] = f":{relation['target_label']}"
            filtered_df.repartition(1).write.format(FORMAT).mode('overwrite').options(**neo4jconfig).save()
```

```
for edge in ["people_friends.delta/"]:
    if "association" not in edge and edge not in done_edges:
        writeEdgeIntoNeo4j(edge, input_path)
```

and it gives me this error org.apache.spark.SparkException

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-4276563430066569> in <module>
      1 for edge in ["people_friends.delta/"]:
      2     if "association" not in edge:
----> 3         write_edge_into_neo4j(edge, input_path)

<command-4276563430066568> in write_edge_into_neo4j(edge, input_path)
     11             neo4jconfig["relationship.source.labels"] = f":{relation['source_label']}"
     12             neo4jconfig["relationship.target.labels"] = f":{relation['target_label']}"
---> 13             filtered_df.repartition(1).write.format(FORMAT).mode('overwrite').options(**neo4jconfig).save()

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
   1132             self.format(format)
   1133         if path is None:
-> 1134             self._jwrite.save()
   1135         else:
   1136             self._jwrite.save(path)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    115     def deco(*a, **kw):
    116         try:
--> 117             return f(*a, **kw)
    118         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    119             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1319.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.OverwriteByExpressionExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.OverwriteByExpressionExec.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result$lzycompute(V2CommandExec.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result(V2CommandExec.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.doExecute(V2CommandExec.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:1080)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:854)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:1080)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:400)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:312)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1054.1 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1054.1 (TID 24864) (10.139.64.35 executor 35): org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.TransientException: Database 'neo4j' not up to the requested version: 4768. Latest database version is 4742
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.Futures.blockingGet(Futures.java:144)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalTransaction.run(InternalTransaction.java:60)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.AbstractQueryRunner.run(AbstractQueryRunner.java:37)
    at org.neo4j.spark.writer.BaseDataWriter.writeBatch(BaseDataWriter.scala:64)
    at org.neo4j.spark.writer.BaseDataWriter.writeBatch(BaseDataWriter.scala:93)
    at org.neo4j.spark.writer.BaseDataWriter.writeBatch(BaseDataWriter.scala:93)
    at org.neo4j.spark.writer.BaseDataWriter.writeBatch(BaseDataWriter.scala:93)
    at org.neo4j.spark.writer.BaseDataWriter.writeBatch(BaseDataWriter.scala:93)
    at org.neo4j.spark.writer.BaseDataWriter.write(BaseDataWriter.scala:45)
    at org.neo4j.spark.writer.Neo4jDataWriter.write(Neo4jDataWriter.scala:9)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.$anonfun$run$1(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:451)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1680)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:487)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.$anonfun$writeWithV2$2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:119)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:813)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1646)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:816)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:672)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.ErrorUtil$InternalExceptionCause
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.ErrorUtil.newNeo4jError(ErrorUtil.java:103)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageDispatcher.handleFailureMessage(InboundMessageDispatcher.java:122)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.common.CommonMessageReader.unpackFailureMessage(CommonMessageReader.java:83)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.common.CommonMessageReader.read(CommonMessageReader.java:59)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageHandler.channelRead0(InboundMessageHandler.java:83)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageHandler.channelRead0(InboundMessageHandler.java:35)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:299)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.MessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageDecoder.java:47)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:314)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:435)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:279)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        ... 1 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2828)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2775)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2769)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2769)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1305)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1305)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1305)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3036)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2977)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2965)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:1067)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJobInternal(SparkContext.scala:2477)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:392)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.TransientException: Database 'neo4j' not up to the requested version: 4768. Latest database version is 4742
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.Futures.blockingGet(Futures.java:144)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalTransaction.run(InternalTransaction.java:60)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.AbstractQueryRunner.run(AbstractQueryRunner.java:37)
    at org.neo4j.spark.writer.BaseDataWriter.writeBatch(BaseDataWriter.scala:64)
    at org.neo4j.spark.writer.BaseDataWriter.writeBatch(BaseDataWriter.scala:93)
    at org.neo4j.spark.writer.BaseDataWriter.writeBatch(BaseDataWriter.scala:93)
    at org.neo4j.spark.writer.BaseDataWriter.writeBatch(BaseDataWriter.scala:93)
    at org.neo4j.spark.writer.BaseDataWriter.writeBatch(BaseDataWriter.scala:93)
    at org.neo4j.spark.writer.BaseDataWriter.write(BaseDataWriter.scala:45)
    at org.neo4j.spark.writer.Neo4jDataWriter.write(Neo4jDataWriter.scala:9)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.$anonfun$run$1(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:451)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1680)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:487)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.$anonfun$writeWithV2$2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:119)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:813)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1646)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:816)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:672)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
    Suppressed: org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.ErrorUtil$InternalExceptionCause
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.ErrorUtil.newNeo4jError(ErrorUtil.java:103)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageDispatcher.handleFailureMessage(InboundMessageDispatcher.java:122)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.common.CommonMessageReader.unpackFailureMessage(CommonMessageReader.java:83)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.common.CommonMessageReader.read(CommonMessageReader.java:59)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageHandler.channelRead0(InboundMessageHandler.java:83)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.InboundMessageHandler.channelRead0(InboundMessageHandler.java:35)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:299)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.inbound.MessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageDecoder.java:47)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:314)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:435)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:279)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        ... 1 more
```

I have read the this could be I may be wrong but what was the cause of the "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job aborted" error. This error sometimes occur if your JAR version is incompatible with other JAR's

And Other times The error usually occurs when there is memory intensive operation and there is less memory

But i'm not sure maybe there is other source of the issue that i couldn't see

Answer (score 0):

```
Error - Database 'neo4j' not up to the requested version: 4768. Latest database version is 4742
```

The error says Database 'neo4j' not up to the requested version: `4768`. Latest database version is `4742`. This is common error for ‘neo4j’

There is a version problem between the driver and the database version. You need to update the database and driver to the latest version.